# Delete cookies using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to delete cookies using Selenium IDE. `deleteCookie` and `deleteAllVisibleCookies` don't work.

Comment: how do you know it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

I got around that problem by adding the script and calling it before each test ( calling from the Selenium IDE "open yourdomain/clear_cookies.php" )

clear_cookies.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-100000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-100000, '/');
        setcookie($name, '', time()-100000, '/', '.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }
}
```